# Unable to create database : Android error

Tags: android, database

I am trying to get data from local database but whenever screen opens i am getting error like

```
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934): Process: com.appworld.detail, PID: 13934
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934): java.lang.Error: Unable to create database
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at com.appworld.detail.Name.onCreate(BankName.java:47)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-16 03:54:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(13934):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is as below.

```
DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(BankName.this);
        databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

        try {
            databaseOpenHelper.createDataBase();
            try {
                databaseOpenHelper.openDataBase();
                List<String> labels = databaseOpenHelper.getAOne();
                databaseOpenHelper.close();

                this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.site_list_row, R.id.title , labels);
                setListAdapter(this.adapter);
                getListView().setChoiceMode(2);
                this.edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new textListener());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
```

and inside databaseopenhelper :

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        getReadableDatabase();
        close();
        copyDataBase();
    }
```

i don't know what is wrong with my code... Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You might be able to better figure out what's causing the error by changing the IOException catch to e.printStackTrace() or similar code, as it might give an indication as to why the database can't be created.

Comment: you should not create a database like this,  check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).